# How to extract country-specific data using rtweet->search_fullarchive->place_country: commands?

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis, rtweet

I need to extract Twitter data, specific to a country using the `place_country:` keyword in the `search_fullarchive` command.

```
x<-search_fullarchive("keyword", n=100,fromDate ="202003151558", toDate="202004101900",env_name="name",parse=TRUE,token = Token, place_country:"US")
```

After execution, I get the error: 
"object 'place_country' not found."

Answer (score 0):

search_fullarchive() sends requests to the premium Twitter API which uses other operators than the free API. 
You have to use the place: operator in the search query instead.
Type ?search_fullarchive to see the limited documentation on this.
Or look at a few imperfect examples here: 
[How to define search queries in rtweet fullarchive and 30day search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61483036/how-to-define-search-queries-in-rtweet-fullarchive-and-30day-search)

Answer (score 0):

Have you figure this out? If not, I had the same issue and I can help.

Your operator `place_country:US` should be in the keyword search argument `x <- search_fullarchive(q = "place_country:US", n=100,fromDate ="202003151558", toDate="202004101900",env_name="name",parse=TRUE,token = Token)`

Cheers!

Comment: How to add a hashtag and a country name like covid and US ?

Comment: I think you can just add replica of this code with your objects: `search_fullarchive("#covid-19", q = "place_country:US", n=100,fromDate ="202003151558", toDate="202004101900", env_name="name", parse=TRUE, token = Token)`