# How to define search queries in rtweet fullarchive and 30day search

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

It's not in the Rtweet-documentation how to do this properly with the additional operators available for search_fullarchive and search_30days.
It just says that the string should follow directly after the operator: , for example: place:California. And that OR can be used to search for multiple phrases.

My attempts:

```
queryohio <- '(place:OH OR place:Ohio OR place:Columbus)(corona OR covid19 OR virus)'
queryohio2 <- 'corona OR covid19 OR virus place:Ohio OR place:Columbus OR place:OH'
querycalifornia <- 'place:CA(corona OR covid19 OR virus) OR place:California(corona OR covid19 OR virus) OR place:"Los Angeles"(corona OR covid19 OR virus)'
```

They all kinda work to varying degrees but I'd be happy to know if there is a correct way to do it.

Comment: what rtweet function have you used for searching?

Comment: search_fullarchive with the premium API. So my requests look something like:
`search_fullarchive(queryohio, n = 150,
                                     env_name = "corona",
                                     fromDate = 202003100500,
                                     toDate =   202003110459)
`